# hangman in python ends after first wrong word

Tags: python

I'm learning python and have been asked to reproduce the hangman game. It's working pretty fine when you guess the letters correctly. The problem is when you type a wrong letter and then the game ends, without reducing lives as stated in the if statement: `if guess not in escolha: vidas -= 1`.

I also tried to indent `if vidas == 0` statement inside the `if guess not in escolha` statement but with the same results.

What am I doing wrong and how could I solve it?

thank you

My code:

```
import random

word_list = ['azul', 'arvore', 'branco', 'estojo', 'lapis']

#ASCII art for hangman
stage = [...]


chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
#test:
print(f'the solution is {chosen_word}')

#variables
lives = 6
end_game = False
display = []
for i in chosen_word:
    display += '_'

#game
while not end_game:
    print(stage[lives])
    guess = input(f'guess a letter: ').lower()
    for i in range(len(chosen_word)):
        letter = chosen_word[i]
        if letter == guess:
            display[i] = letter
        if guess not in chosen_word:
            lives   -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            end_game = True
            print('you lost!')
    print(f"{' '.join(display)}")

    if '_' not in display:
        end_game = True
        print('you win')
```

Comment: Observation 1: `print('Você perdeu!')` is wrongly indented.
Observation 2: `escolha` is not defined

Comment: You are decrementing `vidas` in the loop. So, if the player inputs a wrong letter, it will decrease `vidas` n times. n being `len(eschola)`. So if the `len(eschola)` is same as 6, the `vidas` will hit 0 for one wrong guess

Comment: Instead of adding a translation section, please just [edit] the code into English...

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code that a single solution is hard to offer. You compare all the wrong things it all the wrong ways, your loop is terrible, and the overall game mechanics was a poor choice IMO.

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: You should add a `break` statement.

Comment: `escolha` is not defined...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I thought it wasn't defined either, but it is, it's just mentioned in the translation section. OP needs to update their code so that we don't have to find-and-replace to get a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not *that* bad, but it could be simpler. Have a look at this (and see the comments inline):

```
import random
word_list = ['azul', 'arvore', 'branco', 'estojo', 'lapis']

#ASCII art for hangman
stage = [...]

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
#test:
print(f'the solution is {chosen_word}')

display = ['_' for c in chosen_word] #list comprehension

while lives > 0: #the end_game var is not needed
    guess = input(f'guess a letter: ').lower()
    if guess not in chosen_word: #looping is useless if guess is wrong
        lives   -= 1
        continue
    for i,c in enumerate(chosen_word): #enumerate gives you both the index and the letter
        if c == guess:
            display[i] =  c

    print(f"{' '.join(display)}")
    if '_' not in display:
        print('you win')
        break #exit without executing the else clause
else: #no remaining lives
    print('you lost')
```